# @Viewchild Angular 5, 6 - ElementRef

Tags: javascript, angular, elementref, viewchild

Estoy referenciando a un control mediante ElementRef y para ello uso lo siguiente:

```
 @ViewChild('btnGuardarDatosGenerales') btnGuardarDatosGenerales: ElementRef;
```

la referencia lo necesito para poder llegar a su evento click(), con javascript logro conseguir haciendo:

```
let buttonDG: any = document.getElementsByName('btnGuardarDG')[0];
buttonDG.click();
```

pero al hacerlo con ElementRef no lo consigo :

```
this.btnGuardarDatosGenerales.nativeElement.click();
```

...podría hacerlo con javascript pero no es la idea. Alguna sugerencia, en que me puedo estar equivocando?

Gracias.

Comment: Una consulta, esto lo quieres hacer de esta manera, porque quieres simular el evento click, sin que haya click?
Porque si lo que quieres hacer es definir lo que hará el botón al ser "clickeado" la manera angular sería simplemente definiendo `(click)="loQueDebeHacer()"` en el botón mismo.
Supongo que no es eso, pero si me guío por la pregunta no me quedó muy claro a lo que te refieres con "llegar" a su evento.

Comment: Este será un botón invisible que está dentro de un componente hijo, lo que intento hacer es convocarlo desde otro botón ubicado en el componente padre.

Comment: Ok, entonces añadiré una respuesta que podría servirte.

Comment: Porque tiene que ser un boton invisible? No puede ser una función común y corriente ?

Comment: Te explico: Tengo un componente padre que contiene 3 componentes hijos, en el primer componente hijo existe un botón p, y en los otros dos componentes son dos formularios <form> con su propio botón (invisible) respectivo que hará el submit respectivamente. Lo que intento hacer con el botón del primer componente es que haga submit a los otros dos botones invisible para que hagan submit, ya que no logro hacer submit's directo con el botón principal.

Answer (score 0):

El código que pondré abajo simularía un click en el elemento que necesitas.
Obviamente tendrías que ejecutarlo desde el (click) del botón padre que mencionabas o desde alguna otra parte.  Si realmente estás en el componente padre esto debería funcionar.

```
@ViewChild('btnGuardarDatosGenerales') btnGuardarDatosGenerales: ElementRef;

simularClick() {
    let boton: HTMLElement = this.btnGuardarDatosGenerales.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    boton.click();
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo. Te cuento que ya lo intente de esta forma, si hace la referencias a :

"this.btnGuardarDatosGenerales"

pero me arroja undefined al usar .nativeElement, por lo tanto la variable boton me arroja null.

Comment: Te dice algo como Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined?
Si te sale eso quizás no declaraste elementRef o lo colocaste en el constructor en lugar de como una variable local.
Será?

Comment: Lo otro puede ser que cuando intentas invocarlo, **aún no "existe" tu botón como elemento html**, quizás todo esto lo haces en el **ngOnInit**.  Si lo haces ahí es posible que aún no esté listo el botón cuando intentas instanciarlo (Es un problema común).  Podrías implementar el **AfterViewInit** y colocar ahí tu código para instanciar el elemento.

Comment: De por si cuando ya referencio ya no es necesario declararlo en el constructor, y como prueba de ello es que si logra instanciar a this.btnGuardarDatosGenerales pues al hacer debugger logro ver el DOM del botón.

Comment: Podrías probar hacerlo en el AfterViewInit de todas formas?
Es raro que te de ese error con el código que te di.

Comment: Me sigue arrojando : "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined" te cuento que estoy usando la ultima versión de Angular 6.

Comment: Otra cosa.

**'btnGuardarDatosGenerales' no es el id del botón**, verdad?
no es **id="btnGuardarDatosGenerales"**

Porque En este contexto debería ser...

**#btnGuardarDatosGenerales**

**Haz el siguiente ejercicio.**

Coloca en tu botón (hijo) #boton
y lo instancias con @ViewChild('boton') bla bla... lo que ya sabemos.

Porque ese es otro **error común**, el de pensar que se usará id cuando **se debe usar una variable de template.**

Y recuerda que probablemente **boton no estará seteado antes que  ngAfterViewInit() sea llamado.**

**Intenta mezclar todo esto.**

Comment: No, no es el id. Tiene la interpolación <button #btnGuardarDatosGenerales... Si está instanciando, pero no reconoce nativeElement.

Comment: Mmm, tendríamos que ver más código para poder ayudarte entonces, porque así como dices que se da todo sumado a las respuestas que no te han servido, no podremos ayudarte sin una visión mas amplia :/
Componentes, html, ts. etc.

Comment: Si, se me hace que no estas dando toda la información minima necesaria.

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de estar usando la referencia del botón después del `AfterViewInit`. Además usar el identificador `btnGuardarDatosGenerales` tiene que estar en el botón de modo:

```
<button #btnGuardarDatosGenerales ...> ...</botton>
```

De esa manera el `@ViewChild('btnGuardarDatosGenerales')` tendrá acceso a él.

Te dejo un [Stackblitz funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ffrcl9).

Comment: Mi botón si tiene el identificador, como prueba de ello es que si hace la instancia. Tu **Stackblitz** está vacío :-)

Comment: Si, no habia guardado los cambios. Ya podés revisarlo.

Comment: He intentado replicar la solución acorde a mi necesidad ya que uso varios componentes hijos [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o6nk9j) y si me funciona, lo he hecho tal cual en mi codigo fuente pero me arroja el siguiente error : _TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined_

Comment: Entonces en Stackblitz te funciona pero no así en tu computadora?

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate de estar usando el método ngAfterViewInit() cuando intentas acceder a nativeElement. Esto garantizará que el elemento esté disponible después de que la vista se haya inicializado.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.btnGuardarDatosGenerales.nativeElement.click();
}
```